# python sigint e ctrl c apresentam efeitos diferentes

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, linux, thread

Olá, preciso rodar um executável feito em c,esse executavel executa operações em uma placa e escreve em um arquivo, o problema é que o evento de escrita ocorre quando o programa recebe um ctrl+c. tentei mandar um sigint(até onde sei são equivalentes) mas isso fez com que a execuçao terminasse imediatamente sem escrever no arquivo.
meu codigo:

```
def run(tempo):
proc = subprocess.Popen(["nke/NKE0.7e/terminal64","--plot"], shell=False)
time.sleep(tempo)
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
```

abaixo a saida geradar pelo sigint e a saida gerada pelo ctrl+c
[image: sigint]imagem com sigint
[image: ctrlC]imagem com ctrl+c
como podem ver na segunda a saida é diferente, na primeira a execução simplesmente termina